# std::move in initializer lists

Tags: c++, optimization, reference

I often see the following idiom in production code: A value argument (like a shared pointer) is handed into a constructor and shall be copied once. To ensure this, the argument is wrapped into a `std::move` application. Hating boilerplate code and formal noise I wondered if this is actually necessary. If I remove the application, at least gcc 7 outputs some different assembly.

```
#include <memory>

class A
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> p;
    public:
    A(std::shared_ptr<int> p) : p(std::move(p)) {} //here replace with p(p)

    int get() { return *p; }
};

int f() 
{
    auto p = std::make_shared<int>(42);
    A a(p);
    return a.get();
}
```

[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/Tu7qj3) shows you the difference. While I am not certain what is the most efficient approach here, I wonder if there is an optimization that allows to treat `p` as a rvalue reference in that particular location? It certainly is a named entity, but that entity is "dead" after that location anyway.

Is it valid to treat a "dead" variable as a rvalue reference? If not, why?

Comment: What if you want to use it more than once (it's more likely than you think)? You'd have to signal it *shouldn't* be consumed instead. Opt-in is how most things in C++ work.

Comment: The thing is, I do not use it after the initialization (and not even before, too). The compiler should be able to see that with a basic liveness analysis. The question is: Why is it not allowed to treat the variable as a rvalue reference here.

Comment: `shared_ptr` is a special case here ... its copy operation is to make another pointer to the same managed object.  Are you intending specifically to ask about shared_ptr?  This differs from most objects which do a complete copy of their state when copied.

Comment: There isn't any "treating as rvalue reference" in this code, could you indicate more clearly what you are talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the body of the constructor, there are two `p` objects, the ctor argument and `this->p`. Without the `std::move`, they're identical. That of course means the ownership is shared between the two pointers. This must be achieved in a thread-safe way, and is expensive.

But optimizing this out is quite hard. A compiler can't generally deduce that ownership is redundant. By writing `std::move` yourself, you make it unambiguously clear that the ctor argument `p` does not need to retain ownership.

Comment: Are you saying that the naming is the argument here (member and constructor argument having the same name)? If I am not mistaken, std::move tells the compiler that its argument can be treated like a temporary. But shouldn't it be easy to tell that from the fact that the name of the variable does not occur after that point?

Comment: @choeger: No, names are irrelevant here. The important fact is that they would hold the same pointer value, if not for the `std::move`. And yes, it's easy here to tell that the function argument `p` is not used here. That's far less common in real code, which is more complex. As soon as the compiler sees `p->Foo`, which really is `p.operator->`, you'd need flow analysis to determine whether how big the effective scope is.